# Increase count and decrease count when action is dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently developing a front end application using react-redux. But I am very new to this language.

So basically I have the following UI

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is whenever users increase or decrease the option, it will store to the store procedure, and finally make an API call to backend and calculate pricing.

Before API call, my idea is I will let users to increase/decrease the option and finally when the user is done, i will take that array of object and submit to the api endpoint.

Unfortunately, It seems like the following scenario is failed.

- I increase option 1, it will  save to the state as an array of object
  first time with quantity and optionId  [OK]
- After that, I will increase the option 2, since it is the new option,
  I will push the object to the existing array. [OK]
- When I try to increase option 1 again, it has to check whether option
  1 is already inside the array, if there is option 1, it will just
  increase that option quantity. but my code does not behave that way. [FAILED]

below is my Component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {handleIncreaseOption} from '../actions/option';
import {Button, Card, Col, Row, Statistic} from "antd";
import {MinusOutlined, PlusOutlined} from '@ant-design/icons';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
const {Meta} = Card;

 class FlavourCard extends Component {

     state = {
         quantity: 0,
         optionId: this.props.optionId
     }

    increase = () => {
        let count = this.state.quantity + 1;
        this.setState({
            quantity: count,
            optionId: this.props.optionId
        }, function(){

            console.log('this state before going in', this.state);

            this.props.dispatch(handleIncreaseOption(this.state));
        });


    }

    decline = () => {
        let count = this.state.count - 1;
        if (count < 0) {
            count = 0;
        }
        this.setState({count: count});
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    render() {
        const {flavourImg, itemTitle} = this.props;

        return (
            <Card
                hoverable
                cover={<img alt="example" className="flavour-img" src={flavourImg}/>}
            >
                <Meta
                    title={itemTitle}
                    style={{textAlign: 'center'}}
                    description={
                        <Row justify="start" gutter={12}>
                            <Col span={10} style={{textAlign: 'right', paddingTop: '6px'}}>
                                <Button onClick={this.decline} size="small">
                                    <MinusOutlined/>
                                </Button>
                            </Col>

                            <Col span={4}>
                                <Statistic value={this.state.quantity} style={{fontSize: '10px'}}/>
                            </Col>

                            <Col span={10} style={{textAlign: 'left', paddingTop: '6px'}}>
                                <Button onClick={this.increase} size="small">
                                    <PlusOutlined/>
                                </Button>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    }
                />
            </Card>

        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
     return{
         loadingBar: state.loadingBar
     }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps) (FlavourCard)
```

This is my action class

```
export const RETRIEVE_OPTIONS = 'RETRIEVE_OPTIONS';
export const INCREASE_OPTIONS = 'INCREASE_OPTIONS';

export function receiveOptions( option ) {
    return {
        type: RETRIEVE_OPTIONS,
        option
    }
}

export function handleIncreaseOption ( option ) {
    return {
        type: INCREASE_OPTIONS,
        option
    }
}
```

This is my reducer

```
import {RETRIEVE_OPTIONS, INCREASE_OPTIONS} from "../actions/option";

export default function option ( state = null , action )
{
    switch (action.type) {
        case RETRIEVE_OPTIONS:
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action
            }

        case INCREASE_OPTIONS:

            if (  !state.hasOwnProperty('addOption') ) {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    addOption: [
                                    {
                                        quantity: action.option.quantity,
                                        optionId: action.option.optionId
                                    }
                                ]
                }
            }

            state.addOption.map((opt) => {
                if(opt.optionId === action.option.optionId) {
                    opt.quantity = action.option.quantity;
                }else {
                    let originalAddOption = state.addOption;

                    originalAddOption.push({
                        quantity: action.option.quantity,
                        optionId: action.option.optionId
                    })

                }
                return {
                    ...state,
                    ...action
                }
            })


        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I believe that my "INCREASE_OPTIONS" reducer is something wrong, because, the correct logic should be when there is a new optionId, it will add in as a new object, and if the optionId is existing one, it will just increase the entity. For my current code, whenever I make a second option to increase, it will just add in a new object with new quantity value. I have attached the console result below

[image]

How can I achieve when there is existing option, just increase/decrease the quantity and if option is newly added, make a new object and push to the array? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you creating local state for count but then also try to save it redux state? It's best to save count in redux state when it's needed by other components and just get it from the redux state in the map state to props.

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong. My idea is I will update the state before pumping data into the redux state so that i can know which option has how many quantities.

Comment: Duplicating state for no reason is not a good idea. In map state you can get the count (default to 0 in the selector if not found), the reducer is totally wrong for increase and mutates state.

Comment: Can you give me some straight forward answers? because I am totally lost.

Comment: Is it ok for the FlavourCard to be a functional component? It's a pita to work with react-redux connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a functional example, you only need to pass id to the increaseOption action creator:

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
const { createSelector } = Reselect;

const initialState = {
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
    },
  ],
};
//action types
const INCREASE_OPTIONS = 'INCREASE_OPTIONS';
//action creators
const increaseOption = (id) => ({
  type: INCREASE_OPTIONS,
  payload: id,
});
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === INCREASE_OPTIONS) {
    const addOption = state.addOption || [];
    const exist = addOption.some(
      ({ optionId }) => optionId === payload
    );
    return {
      ...state,
      addOption: exist
        ? addOption.map((option) =>
            option.optionId === payload
              ? { ...option, quantity: option.quantity + 1 }
              : option
          )
        : addOption.concat({
            optionId: payload,
            quantity: 1,
          }),
    };
  }
  return state;
};

//selectors
const selectData = (state) => state.data;
const selectOption = (state) => state.addOption || [];
const createSelectOption = (id) =>
  createSelector([selectOption], (options) => {
    const option = options.find(
      ({ optionId }) => optionId === id
    );
    return option ? option.quantity : 0;
  });
const createSelectItem = (itemId) =>
  createSelector([selectData], (data) =>
    data.find(({ id }) => id === itemId)
  );
const createSelectCardProp = (id) =>
  createSelector(
    [createSelectOption(id), createSelectItem(id)],
    (option, item) => ({ option, item })
  );
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (n) => (a) => n(a))
  )
);
const FlavourCard = React.memo(function FlavourCard({
  id,
}) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const selectProps = React.useMemo(
    () => createSelectCardProp(id),
    [id]
  );
  const props = useSelector(selectProps);
  return (
    <button onClick={() => dispatch(increaseOption(id))}>
      id: {props.item.id} count:{props.option}
    </button>
  );
});

const App = () => {
  const data = useSelector(selectData);
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(({ id }) => (
        <FlavourCard key={id} id={id} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @Achilles Note that I added reselect, that is standard in [redux template application](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#create-a-react-redux-app). I wrote a tutorial on selectors with reselect [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple problems in the reducer.

The first issue is that you are trying to update the state object directly. This will not work, you have to set state to a new object.

The second issue is how you are using the map function. It looks like you are using it to update a value if it exists, or add a new entry if it does not. You might have to separate that out and first check if it exists, if so do an update, if not add a new element. Then for each opt in the array, you return an object containing the entire state and action, which I don't think is your intention.

Try out something like this in the reducer:

```
case INCREASE_OPTIONS: {

    if (  !state.hasOwnProperty('addOption') ) {
        return {
            ...state,
            addOption: [
                            {
                                quantity: action.option.quantity,
                                optionId: action.option.optionId
                            }
                        ]
        }
    }

    let updated = false;

    // For every element, check if we find the id to modify
    // Map returns an array. Does not modify in place.
    let addOptCopy = state.addOption.map((opt) => {
        if(opt.optionId === action.option.optionId) {
            opt.quantity = action.option.quantity;
            updated = true;
        }
        return opt;
    });

    // If nothing was updated, push new element
    if(!updated){
        addOptCopy.push({
            quantity: action.option.quantity,
            optionId: action.option.optionId
        })
    }

    // return the new state
    return {
            ...state,
            addOption: [...addOptCopy]
           }
}
```

---

As one of the comments on your post suggested, it may be an over complication to be keeping two states, using the components state plus redux state and keeping them in sync. You can do the increase and decrease within the reducer, and get the state from props in the components by linking it in `mapStateToProps`.

Lastly, there seems to be a typo in the `decrease` function, you are setting `count` in state instead of `quantity`.

Comment: You are my lifesaver, Thank you. I will try to use increase and decrease within the reducer as well.